# How to pass data from form to router

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, csv

I am new to java script and `node.js` ; in case of some mistakes. Please forgive me.

I am trying to write a simple `Node.Js` server side application.

What I am trying to achieve here is. On the view, I have text box and a submit button. When I pass the submit button. The data written in the text box should be passed to router(`index.js`) and that shall process it.

Please see my code below.

**view code**

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  form#formReadCSV(name="readCSVFile",method="post",action="/readCSVFile")
      input#inputCompleteCSVPath(type="text", placeholder="Complete Path" name="fileCSV")
      button#btnOpenFile(type="submit") Submit 


router(index.js)
```

---

```
router.post('/readCSVFile',function(req,res){

    /*Read the complete Path*/
    var fileName = req.body.fileCSV;

    //console.log(fileName);

    var reader = csv.createCSVFileReader(fileName,{
                          'separator':',',
                          'quote':'"',
                          'escape':'"',
    });

    reader.addListener('data',function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

    reader.addListener('end', function() {
        console.log("END");
        res.render('success_csv_upload', {message : "Successfully consumed the CSV file"});
    });
```

Now when press the submit button. It is some how is not reaching to the router. I am getting the below error

```
csv is not defined
ReferenceError: csv is not defined
    at /Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/routes/index.js:26:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at next (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at /Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:234:24
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:12)
    at /Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:228:12
    at Function.match_layer (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:295:3)
    at next (/Users/rajesh/Documents/NodeProject/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:10)
```

Is there any way through which I can debug the `node.js`.

Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install module csv

```
npm install ya-csv
```

Add it to your code

```
var csv = require('ya-csv');
```

Example:

Modules

```
npm install ya-csv
npm install multer
```

Form

```
form#formReadCSV(name='readCSVFile', method='post', action='/readCSVFile', enctype='multipart/form-data')
  input#inputCompleteCSVPath(type='file', placeholder='Complete Path', name='fileCSV')
  button#btnOpenFile(type='submit') Submit
```

JS

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var router  = express.Router()
var csv     = require('ya-csv');
var multer  = require('multer');

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}))

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

router.post('/readCSVFile', function (req, res) {
  var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader(req.files.fileCSV.path, {'separator':',', 'quote':'"', 'escape':'"'});

  reader.addListener('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

  reader.addListener('end', function() {
    res.send('File was processed');
  });
});

app.use('/', router);
app.listen(3000);
```